# How to direct user to an specific page depending on selection they made after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jss

I have created a list with 6 options and users can only select one. I want that whenever a user selects an option from the list after they submit the form it directs them to a specific page depending on which selection.

Eg. I have 3 options

1. Facebook
2. Youtube
3. Twitter

If the user selects option 1 after submission it will direct them to the Facebook page, if they select option 2 it will direct them to a youtube page .. etc

Comment: Could you also post your attempts?

Comment: What do you mean, my attempts ? Relating to what ?

Comment: I mean your code.

Comment: That's the thing I don't have any!

Comment: Then are you trying to use any backends? Or just frontend with `javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. You just have to get the value from the selector & use JS to open that link.
 Check my solution for reference -

[solution on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fq71ekd/)

```js
function myFunction() {
let link = 
    document.getElementById("social").value
  let fb = "https://facebook.com"
  let tw = "https://twitter.com"
  if(link == 'fb') {
    window.open(fb);
  } else if (link == 'tw') {
    window.open(tw);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="social">
  <option value="fb">Facebook</option>
  <option value="tw">Twitter</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
go to site
</button>
```

This somehow doesn't work here, working on JS Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<form>
    <select name="" id="target">
        <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
        <option value="twitter">Twitter</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="sub_button">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    const data = {
        facebook: 'https://facebook.com',
        youtube: 'https://youtube.com',
        twitter: 'https://twitter.com',
    }
    document.querySelector('#sub_button').onclick = function() {
        let target = document.querySelector('#target').value;
        window.location.href = data[target];
    }
</script>
</body>
```